# display error to user if a search text not found

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have this jquery script that binds to the jstree and searches the tree, if found highlights the three nodes. Which works. But I like to alert a messages to the user if the search test is not found. Any ideas how I would do this?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function myFunction()
    {
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var value=document.getElementById("search_field").value; 

        $("#search_tree").click(function () { 

            $("#tree").jstree("search",value);

    });

     document.getElementById("search_field").value='';
     }); 
    }
```

html:

```
<fieldset id="search">

    <input type="text" name="search_field" id="search_field" value="" />
    <button id="search_tree" onclick="myFunction()"> Search</button>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an idea from the code below. If you need any further help please provide working jsfiddle sample and I'll modify the code to work with yours.

```
$("div#jstree").bind("search.jstree", function (e, data) {
    //document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="Found " + data.rslt.nodes.length + " nodes matching '" + data.rslt.str + "'.";
   if (data.rslt.nodes.length == 0){
    alert("No search results found");
   }
});
```

Comment: I cannot create a jsfiddle for some reason. My origial code is in the posting. I tried something like this: $("#tree").jstree("search",value). function (e, data) {
    if (data.rslt.nodes.length == 0){
    alert("No search results found");
   } game me an error though

Comment: any ideas how can I tackle this?

Comment: As of jsTree 3.0.0-beta8, this is: if (data.res.length == 0)